# How can iPhone be used when wearing gloves?

Tags: iphone

In colder weather wearing gloves is essential. Looks like iPhone 4 completely ignores touches of fingers in gloves. So I sometimes even see people controlling their iPhones by touching them with their noses.

What are the limitations of how iPhone can be controlled? How can it be used by a person wearing gloves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The screen is a [capacitive touch device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing) so it depends on a conductive item contacting it. A number of companies have produced gloves with appropriately conductive finger pads.

Comment: Good answer but it would've been more helpful to add direct links to a couple of good vendors. (Oh, and if you want to make this even more attractive and earn plently of upvotes, *include example pics*.)

Answer (score 14):

I like these lambswool gloves by [Dots](http://www.dotsgloves.com). I imagine they use some sort of conductive thread woven in the fabric, and they're quite affordable at $15.50 to $20.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You could be like the South Koreans and [use sausages](http://www.engadget.com/2010/02/11/south-korean-iphone-users-turn-to-sausages-as-a-cold-weather-me/).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to use special stylus like this: http://www.tenonedesign.com/stylus.php

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.topiphoneresource.info/best-iphone-gloves/) you'll find a list of 11 different gloves to use with your iPhone...

Answer (score 5):

You can buy conductive thread and then weave the thread into any pair gloves that you own.  There's a really overview of what conductive thread is and more information of the different types here: http://www.fashioningtech.com/profiles/blogs/conductive-thread-overview, and there is instructions on how to do this along with a video demo here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-A-Glove-Work-With-A-Touch-Screen/