# Is there a way to build a simple iPad pen yourself?

Tags: ipad

I wonder about the technology used by the multitouch and the pens and brushes that are sold. Is this really high technology or can we build a pen for ipad ourself ?

Comment: See a weird South Korean solution in this other thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/how-can-iphone-be-used-when-wearing-gloves

Comment: Also check [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/pages/search/search.jsp?q=ipad+stylus)!

Answer (score 1):

Well, http://techcrunch.com/2010/05/05/diy-ipad-stylus-actually-extremely-easy-to-make/ looks interesting.

It seems that the ipad screen reacts to conductive surfaces, so if you can make one of those your point on a stylus, you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Walt MossPuppet video on making on a stylus out of a protein bar wrapper:

http://mosspuppet.com/2010/09/20/video-how-to-make-an-ipad-stylus-with-a-protein-bar-wrapper/